# How do I make this regex rewrite rule work for both with / and without /?

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I made the following redirect rule to be used in htaccess for Wordpress which seems to work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /nl/my-impact/
RewriteRule ^nl/(.+)$ $1nl/ [R=301,L]
```

But it should redirect both:

- `https://alivetoearth.org/nl/my-impact/florian`
- `https://alivetoearth.org/nl/my-impact/florian/`

to:
`https://alivetoearth.org/my-impact/florian/nl/`

How can I make sure it works in both cases?

Now I can just make it work in one or the other. If there is a better way to write the entire redirect I would also love to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this redirect rule:

```bash
RewriteRule ^(nl)/([^/]+/[^/]+)/?$ /$2/$1/ [R=301,L,NC]
```